# Verification of Proof: "$K$ is compact $\implies$ $\exists \inf K \in K$ and $\exists \sup K \in K$"

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, convergence-divergence

I hope life is going okay for everyone; I am hoping someone here can comment on aspects of my proof's accuracy, coherence, simplicity, readability, etc.. Anything really goes, I am trying to improve all fronts of mathematical intuition - **please criticize as much of my work as you can.** Note that the problem below is an exercise (3.3.1.) in *Understanding Analysis ed.2* by S. Abbott.

#### Problem

Show that if $K$ is compact and nonempty, then $\sup K$ and $\inf K$ both exist and are elements of $K$.

#### Definitions

*Compact Set*: A set $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is compact if every sequence in $K$ has a subsequence that converges to a limit that is also in $K$.

*Closed Set*: A set $F \subseteq R$ is closed if it contains its limit points.

*Bounded Set*:  A set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is bounded if there exists $M > 0$ such that $|a|\leq M$ for all $a \in A$.

*Theorem 2.5.2.* - Subsequences of a convergent sequence converge to the same limit as the original sequence.

*Theorem 3.3.4.* - A set $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.

*Lemma 1.3.8.*

1. Assume $s \in R$ is an upper bound for a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Then, $s = \sup A$ if and only if, for every choice of $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an element $a \in A$ satisfying $s - \epsilon < a$.
2. Assume $i \in R$ is a lower bound for a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Then, $i = \inf A$ if and only if, for every choice of $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an element $a \in A$ satisfying $a < i + \epsilon $.

*Axiom of Completeness*: Every nonempty set of real numbers that is bounded above has a least upper bound and every nonempty set of real numbers that is bounded below has a greatest lower bound.

*Limit Point*: A point $x$ is a limit point of a set $A$ if every $\epsilon$-neighborhood $\mathcal{B}_{\epsilon}(x)$ of $x$ intersects the set $A$ at some point other than $x$.

#### My Proof

$\text{     }$ Suppose that a set $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is compact and nonempty. Let $\alpha = \sup K$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. First we want to show $\alpha$ exists and $\alpha \in K$. By Theorem 3.3.4., $K$ is bounded, i.e. there exists $M > 0$ such that $-M \leq k \leq M$ for all $k \in K$. This implies that $\alpha$ exists by the Axiom of Completeness. Now let $\epsilon > 0$. By Lemma 1.3.8. we know that there exists an element $k \in K$ satisfying $\alpha - \epsilon < k$. In particular, we have $\alpha - \epsilon < k < \alpha + \epsilon$, which means that $k \in \mathcal{B}_{\epsilon}(\alpha)$. Moreover, $\alpha$ is a limit point of $K$ since $k \in \mathcal{B}_{\epsilon}(\alpha) \cap K$. Since $K$ is closed by Theorem 3.3.4., then we have $\alpha \in K$, as desired.

$\text{     }$ Let $\beta = \inf K$ for some $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$. What remains to be shown is that $\beta$ exists and $\beta \in K$. Since $K$ is bounded by Theorem 3.3.4., the Axiom of Completeness implies that $\beta$ exists. Let $\epsilon > 0$. By Lemma 1.3.8. we know that there exists an element $k \in K$ satisfying $\beta + \epsilon > k$. In particular, we have $\beta + \epsilon > k > \beta - \epsilon$, which means that $k \in \mathcal{B}_{\epsilon}(\beta)$. Since $k \in \mathcal{B}_{\epsilon}(\beta) \cap K$, we have that $\beta$ is a limit point of $K$. Thus, $\beta \in K$ since $K$ is closed.

Comment: Thank you for spelling out your reasoning so completely. +1. I do not see how it follows that $k$ being in both $K$ and a ball of epsilon radius around $\alpha$ (for just one value of epsilon) implies that $\alpha$ is a limit point of $K$. Some rewording might help. It is probably something to do with an ordering of quantifiers.

Comment: You are correct; I should have written "Now let arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$" in the first paragraph and "Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary". Lemma 1.3.8. applies for every choice of $\epsilon$, and I neglected to remark on this in my proof. Specifying $\alpha - \epsilon < k < \alpha + \epsilon$, $\forall \epsilon > 0$, would have made it clearer that $k \in \mathcal{B}_{\epsilon_1}(\alpha) \cap \mathcal{B}_{\epsilon_2}(\alpha) \cap \dotsm$. Also, I should write $k \in \mathcal{B}_{\epsilon}(\alpha) \cap K$, $\forall \epsilon > 0$ in para. 1, not $k \in \mathcal{B}_{\epsilon}(\alpha) \cap K$

Comment: @leslietownes Thank you for noticing this, I really appreciate it.

Comment: $\sup K$ could be maximum and an isolated point of $K$, so the $\varepsilon$ argument  is only needed if $\sup K$ is not a mximum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is fine.
It's basically 3 observations:

- $K$ is compact so $K$ is bounded so $\inf K$ and $\sup K$ exist.
- Always $\sup K$ and $\inf K$ are limit points of $K$ (which is not strictly true, consider a finite set e.g, though they are adherence points of $K$).
- $K$ compact implies is $K$ closed so it contains its limit points (or rather its adherent points).

Comment: When I was initially thinking about the proof, it seemed more complicated and I was not particularly confident with my answer. Framing the result as these three observations helps; thank you for this. I will use this answer to close the question with the check mark.